# is "Cleaner the room is Healthier it will be" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, definite-article, comparative-constructions, minor-sentences

Is this correct if I write "Cleaner the room is Healthier it will be".

Is it saying If my room is cleaner today, it will improve my health in future (as there is 'Healthier it **will** be').

If so, what should I write to convey if I want to say. If my room is cleaner, it is healthier.

*No future tense in the sense of sentence*

Comment: Maybe... *Cleaner the room, healthier an individual living in it.*

Comment: @MaulikV thanks, can you write it down as an answer, so I can provide proper reward!

Comment: It's more spoken (informal) than written. It was a quick tip from my mobile. Michael is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael's answer addresses the pattern correctly, but it's also worth calling out your use of "it"

> The cleaner the room, the healthier *it* will be.

Here, "it" refers to a noun. But the only noun in the sentence is "room." Perhaps you mean to say that the room is healthy. I can think of a number of cases where that would be a reasonable observation:

1. There is a healthy amount of natural light or plants or something else in the room.
2. The room is clean so as to promote health
3. The room is in a hospital
4. The room is a healthy size

... Etc.

However, it sounds to me that what you mean is...

> The cleaner the room, the healthier its resident

This is specifically referring to the health of the person who lives in the clean room.

Depending on context, either of these might be correct.

---

It's also worth noting that the use of "will be" to end the sentence is implied in the latter case. We couldn't drop it from the first sentence because ending a sentence with "it" is awkward there.

You could also use present tense

> The cleaner the room, the healthier it is
>   The cleaner my room, the healthier I am

When the use of "will be" is implied, the tense is not inherently implied, so the reader could interpret our previous example as

> The cleaner the room, the healthier its resident [is/will be]

Either could be correct.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the following grammar pattern:

> The healthier you are, the longer you will live.
>
> The faster we move, the sooner we will get there.
>
> The cleaner the room is, the healthier it will be.

If the context is clear, you can even shorten the sentence to just four words:

> The cleaner, the healthier.

Comment: So it is properly written (in question)! can you check Maulik V's comment on the question. These "The cleaner the room is, the healthier it will be." and "Cleaner the room, healthier an individual living in it" two sentences are conveying same meaning ?

Comment: I think what Maulik has written there, although comprehensible, is nevertheless wrong English.

Comment: Oh! has he!? can you please explain me how and where he is wrong there?

Comment: First of all, in order to be proper English, you need to prepend the two adjectives in comparative form with definite articles. Secondly, the second part of the statement doesn't sound complete. I would add *will be* to the end of it. *is* in the first part of the sentence is optional, though: **The cleaner the room is, the healthier an individual living in it will be**.

Comment: OKay, I got that. If you have noticed in my question, my doubt was also because of "**will be**" used in sentence. if we summarize, are these "Cleaner the room is, Healthier it will be" and  "If room is cleaner, it is healthier" sentences conveying same meaning ?

Comment: Basically, yes. They're identical in meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much. Don't mind, I will accept an answer after waiting for proper time.

Comment: No problem. Do as you see fit.